# iPhone - Voice recording using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I have followed a sample code for the above, everything seems to be working fine without a single error, the voice file (.caf) is created successfully.

The only problem is the file is always 29kb and without any sound in it.

I am running the app in my simulator, not sure if I have missed out anything. Is there anything that I need to set for my simulator to work?

Below is my code:

```
-(IBAction) startRecording
{
    NSLog(@"startRecording");
[audioRecorder release];
audioRecorder = nil;

// Init audio with record capability
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
{
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];   
}
else
{
    NSNumber *formatObject;

    switch (recordEncoding) {
        case (ENC_AAC): 
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ALAC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
            break;
        case (ENC_IMA4):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
            break;
        case (ENC_ILBC):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
            break;
        case (ENC_ULAW):
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
            break;
        default:
            formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
    }

    [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
}

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *sourceFilename = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"r.caf"];
NSString *sourcePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:sourceFilename];
[sourceFilename release];

//[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:sourcePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourcePath];

NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];

audioRecorder.delegate = self;

if(!audioRecorder){
    NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [error domain], [error code], [[error userInfo] description]);
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: [error localizedDescription]
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return;
}

if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES){
    [audioRecorder record];
}else {
    int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]); 
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode); 

}
NSLog(@"recording");
}
```

Please advice. Googling up and down and yet can't find the cause of it. Do I need to install soundflower to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that for the audio format of kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, the AVEncoderBitRateKey cannot be set to 12800. Comment off the bit rate statement and the recording works successfully.

Have yet to find out what should be the correct and supported bit rate for kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, but this is at least the answer of the question, for anybody who runs into the same situation like me.

:)

Answer (score 1):

This is all good except your encoder bit rate should be 128000 (128k) not 12800 (12.8k).